# Why Node.js stop working?

Tags: node.js, error-handling

I installed node.js on my server and it's working. But it stops after a while with this error:

```
events.js:77
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
    at Protocol.end (/var/www/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:73:13)
    at Socket.onend (stream.js:79:10)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:122:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:910:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:373:11)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
error: Forever restarting script for 14 time
```

The I run node.js on port `8000` with `socket.io`, `node-mysql` and `mc`.

The file path to the `events.js` is `/node/lib/events.js`.

If I use `forever` I can run it continuously but the error still comes up. It's just restart the script. Not the best solution (better than nothing, but maybe the worst solution).

I'm gonna give a try to the `uncaughtException` but still not the best solution. This code:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  console.log('Caught exception: ' + err);
});
```

Please help me out if you can. Thanks.

Comment: It means just what it says. The MySQL Server you're connecting to closed the connection your application had open. The error is because it was unexpected. It may mean you're trying to leave connections open too long and the server eventually considers it to have timed out. But, it's difficult to say without seeing the code. If you're using [`mysql`](https://npmjs.org/package/mysql), make sure you eventually use `connection.end()`.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for your answere. I had no idea that the `Connection lost` is actually the connection to the database which lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle the error event on your mysql connection. If an event emitter emits the "error" event and it is not handled, an exception is thrown. I am not sure what you are doing in your code, but see below for how you should be handling this:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'me',
  password : 'secret',
});

connection.on('error', function (err) {
    // Handle your error here.
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].solution);
});

connection.end();
```

here is an example of handling disconnects from https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/blob/master/Readme.md#server-disconnects:

```
function handleDisconnect() {
  connection = mysql.createConnection(db_config); // Recreate the connection, since
                                                  // the old one cannot be reused.

  connection.connect(function(err) {              // The server is either down
    if(err) {                                     // or restarting (takes a while sometimes).
      console.log('error when connecting to db:', err);
      setTimeout(handleDisconnect, 2000); // We introduce a delay before attempting to reconnect,
    }                                     // to avoid a hot loop, and to allow our node script to
  });                                     // process asynchronous requests in the meantime.
                                          // If you're also serving http, display a 503 error.
  connection.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('db error', err);
    if(err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') { // Connection to the MySQL server is usually
      handleDisconnect();                         // lost due to either server restart, or a
    } else {                                      // connnection idle timeout (the wait_timeout
       throw err;                                 // server variable configures this)
    });
}

handleDisconnect();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answere. More or less this was what I was looking for. Plus this code https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/blob/master/Readme.md#server-disconnects . If you update your answere I accept it.